# How to print words following an exact term in python

Tags: python, cpu-word, decoding

I need to print the words following 'ed' in a text. However, it doesn't work properly I think there is a problem with the expression "following_word". the text.txt file contains the text: "Ed io timido e cheto ed inesperto," Could you pls help me?

```
with open("text.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as rf:
    text=list(rf)

y=["ed"]

for word in text:
    word_list=word.lower().split()
    for x in word_list:
        if x in y:
            following_word=word_list[word_list.index(y) +1]
            print(x+" "+following_word)
```

the result should be:

ed io

ed inesperto,

Comment: What about splitting by "ed "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For a more concise solution you can use the standard [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) (regular expression) module:

```
import re
search_terms = ["ed"]

for term in search_terms:
    following_words = re.findall(r"%s (\w+)" % term, string.lower())
    print('\n'.join(f'{term} {word}' for word in following_words))
```

Output:

```
ed io
ed inesperto
```

2. For the absolute minimal amount of change to what you already had, use enumerate, and avoid an index-out-of-bounds error by only looking until one before the end of each line:

```
search_terms = ["ed"]

for words_line in text:
    word_list = words_line.lower().split()
    for i, word in enumerate(word_list[:-1]): # only look until the penultimate character
        if word in search_terms:
            following_word = word_list[i + 1]
            print(x + " " + following_word)
```

(Same output)

Comment: The second option you wrote, really works well for me. I simply have a question because I want to understand can you explain to me what i is? Thank you in advance

Comment: And how should I change following_word=word_list[i+1] if I wanted the preceding word of a searched term? Thank you again

Comment: You should only traverse from the second word to the end, if you are possibly getting the preceding word. i.e. `enumerate(word_list[1:])` with `preceding = word_list[i - 1] ` but if you need both preceding _and_ following, then do `enumerate(word_list[1:-1])` (or simply add a check to ensure you're not at one of the ends, to avoid an invalid index error)

Comment: Thank you even if it actually works if a leave enumerate(word_list[:-1]) with preceding=word_list[i-1]. Don't know why but it works whereas if I change to enumerate(word_list[1:]), it doesn't

Comment: Oops, you would need to account for the shift in indexes.. i is offset by 1 smaller, so the preceding would be at indeed i and following would be at i+2

Answer (score 2):

Like I wrote in the comment, split by "ed " like the following:

```
string = "Ed io timido e cheto ed inesperto"
for s in string.lower().split("ed "):
    if len(s):
        print(f"ed {s.split()[0]}")
```